# How to get the unique details from android application?

Tags: android, key, unique

I need to create a unique key for each user by using the unique key's from the application. 
I already fetch the device id, if there anything else as unique?. If yes, please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509951/android-application-unique-license-key

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a unique Android device ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get IMEI number

```
TelephonyManager TM = (TelephonyManager)    getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// IMEI No.
String imeiNo = TM.getDeviceId();

// IMSI No.
String imsiNo = TM.getSubscriberId();

// SIM Serial No.
String simSerialNo  = TM.getSimSerialNumber();

// Android Unique ID
String androidId =    System.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

to your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID returns the Android ID as an unique 64-bit hex string
    private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
But this is known to change on factoru reset and sometimes may return null.
It can also be easily changed on a rooted device.

Some other options are:

1.IMEI

2.IMSI

```
String ts = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(ts);
String imsi = mTelephonyMgr.getSubscriberId();
String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
```

Answer (score 0):

String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);